# Error while running JanusGraph Gremlin console

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am following the steps mentioned here: http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/getting-started.html
and getting error while running the command: `bin/gremlin.sh`

Error Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF-8i
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(StreamEncoder.java:61)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:100)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:231)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:221)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:213)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.PatchedConsoleReader.<init>(PatchedConsoleReader.groovy:32)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.<init>(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:118)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:478)
```

I am using following java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone tell me how should I avoid this error and start working on JanusGraph?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: using Linux Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your stack trace, it looks like the encoding is set to `UTF-8i`, which is not a valid value. See [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) for typical values. Check your [`LC_CTYPE`](https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/jline-2.12/src/main/java/jline/internal/Configuration.java#L214) environment variable or `JAVA_OPTIONS` to see if it attempts to override [`input.encoding`](https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/jline-2.12/src/main/java/jline/internal/Configuration.java#L218) or [`file.encoding`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/nio/charset/Charset.java#l608).

For example, this recreates the stack trace above:

```
$ export JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dinput.encoding=UTF-8i
$ bin/gremlin.sh

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF-8i
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(StreamEncoder.java:61)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(OutputStreamWriter.java:100)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:231)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:221)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:213)
    etc...
```

Unsetting the `JAVA_OPTIONS` variable makes it work again:

```
$ unset JAVA_OPTIONS
$ bin/gremlin.sh

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: janusgraph.imports
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.spark
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin>
```

Comment: No, not working. I unset the JAVA_OPTIONS but still giving the same error.

Tried to print echo $JAVA_OPTIONS, it is showing nothing.

Comment: Is [`LC_CTYPE`](https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/jline-2.12/src/main/java/jline/internal/Configuration.java#L214) or [`TERM`](https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/jline-2.12/src/main/java/jline/TerminalFactory.java#L54) set? `UTF-8i` is somehow coming out of your environment, and you'll need to figure out where that is coming from.

Comment: Or try `env | grep UTF` and see what other variables match.

Comment: Yes Jason, LC_CTYPE was set to en_US.UTF-8i. I changed it to en_US.UTF-8 and now it is working. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `LC_CTYPE`. Glad you got it working.